# In temp table I get this error : Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my script

```
SELECT City, Country, Density, NULL AS CityAvg
INTO #Temp
FROM CityInfo


UPDATE T1
SET CityAvg = (SELECT STDEV(Density) FROM #Temp T2 WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country)
FROM #Temp T1
```

When I execute this I get this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.

I tried to change **NULL** to **0.00** but still same error

```
SELECT City, Country, Density, 0.00 AS CityAvg
INTO #Temp
FROM CityInfo


UPDATE T1
SET CityAvg = (SELECT STDEV(Density) FROM #Temp T2 WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country)
FROM #Temp T1
```

Data Sample

```
Country   City      Density
Australia Melbourne 23.365
Australia Sydney    25.657
Australia Perth     12.374
Canada    Toronto   27.748
Canada    Montreal  22.559
```

How to resolve this issue?

**Note :** This is a very simplified example of my code.

The actual code is more complex so I have to use `#Temp` table and it has to be in `UPDATE` statement

Comment: what's the `density` data type?

Comment: Is your `#Temp` table created via a separate `DDL` or on-the-fly based on the `SELECT INTO`?  What is the data type of the field in which you are trying to store the `CityAvg` value?  What if you explicitly cast your `CityAvg` calculation, something like: `CAST(CityAvg AS DECIMAL(38,5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
SELECT City, Country, Density, NULL AS CityAvg
INTO #Temp
FROM CityInfo;
```

*has* to assign a type to `NULL`.  With no other information, SQL Server assigns it to the `NULL` type.  That is presumably your problem.  You can see this in the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e07e317c4693ff6b7d27c1b3a399d7b).

So, cast this to the type you want:

```
SELECT City, Country, Density, CAST(NULL AS float) as CityAvg
INTO #Temp
FROM CityInfo;
```

Or if you want to copy the same type:

```
SELECT City, Country, Density, (case when 1=0 then Density end) AS CityAvg
```

Once you get that right, you can simplify your query by using window functions:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             STDEV(Density) OVER (PARTITION BY city) as new_cityavg
      FROM #temp t
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET CityAvg = new_cityavg;
```

The window function should have better performance, because it will not repeat the calculation for each city.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [Country] VARCHAR(12) 
   ,[City] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Density] DECIMAL(9, 3)
)

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([Country], [City], [Density])
VALUES ('Australia', 'Melbourne', 23.365)
      ,('Australia', 'Sydney', 25.657)
      ,('Australia', 'Perth',  12.374)
      ,('Canada', 'Toronto', 27.748)
      ,('Canada', 'Montreal', 22.559);



SELECT City, Country, Density, CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(19, 2)) AS CityAvg
INTO #Temp
FROM #DataSource


UPDATE T1
SET CityAvg = (SELECT STDEV(Density) FROM #Temp T2 WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country)
FROM #Temp T1

SELECT *
FROM #Temp;

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

Answer (score -1):

USE THIS

```
UPDATE T1
SET CityAvg = (SELECT STDEV(ISNULL(Population , 0)) FROM #Temp T2 WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country)
FROM #Temp T1

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```